# What consumer group does kafka-console-consumer use

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

When i run kafka-console-consumer like so

```
bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic test
```

What consumer group does it default to? Does it end up using a random consumer group if I don't specify consumer group or link to consumer properties in the command line? How can I check what consumer group was used?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If a group is not specified, the `kafka-console-consumer.sh` generates a random consumer group with this format:

```
console-consumer-${new Random().nextInt(100000)}
```

See the ConsoleConsumer scala class: https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/core/src/main/scala/kafka/tools/ConsoleConsumer.scala#L370

Unfortunately to find the generated group id, you have to:

- look at the console consumer logs
- list all groups (for example using the `kafka-consumer-groups` tool and filter for group starting with `console-consumer-`.

Answer (score 2):

[It uses a random one](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/core/src/main/scala/kafka/tools/ConsoleConsumer.scala), that's not intended to be reused, so there should be no reason to know what it is because it'll be cleaned up when the consumer object is closed

```
consumerProps.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, s"console-consumer-${new Random().nextInt(100000)}")
    // By default, avoid unnecessary expansion of the coordinator cache since
    // the auto-generated group and its offsets is not intended to be used again
    if (!consumerProps.containsKey(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG))
      consumerProps.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, "false")
```