# Kafka console check if my java api correctly consuming message

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I am using kafka cluster version 1.0.2, i want to see all consumer group through kafka console command, but i can't.

i have read the documentation about [kafka-consumer-group.sh](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#basic_ops_consumer_group), which could list all consumer from kafka.

But unfortunately, when i try this command against my kafka cluster

`./kafka-consumer-groups.sh --list --zookeeper localhost:2181`

this only outputting the [generated consumer group](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51672936/6537751)

which preceded by a note, something like this

```
Note: This will only show information about consumers that use ZooKeeper (not those using the Java consumer API).

console-consumer-64217
console-consumer-43716
console-consumer-33231
```

let say i create a spring application which consuming one of the topic like below :

```
@KafkaListener(groupId = "my-group-id", id="consumer-id", topics = "the-topic-supposed-to-consumed")
    public void listen(ConsumerRecord<String, String> message) {
        logger.info("Receive Message : " + message);

        // the rest of the code
    }
```

How can i ensure that my spring application consume incoming message correctly, through kafka console command?

any pointer would be helpful, thank you

Comment: check the consumer position for particular group id `my-group-id`

Answer (score 1):

Isn't this message clear?

> Note: This will only show information about consumers that use ZooKeeper (not those using the Java consumer API).

Use `--bootstrap-server localhost:9092` instead.

```scala
  class ConsumerGroupCommandOptions(args: Array[String]) {
    val ZkConnectDoc = "REQUIRED (for consumer groups based on the old consumer): The connection string for the zookeeper connection in the form host:port. " +
      "Multiple URLS can be given to allow fail-over."
    val BootstrapServerDoc = "REQUIRED (for consumer groups based on the new consumer): The server to connect to."
...
    val NewConsumerDoc = "Use new consumer. This option requires that the 'bootstrap-server' option is used."
...
```

Comment: yes i am aware of the message, so there is no other way? kafka can only list the generated consumer group through its console command?

Comment: @Guntur The console commands are wrappers around Java/Scala code... You could therefore do the same programmatically. The point here is that your consumer group is maintained in Kafka, not Zookeeper, so you need to do a lookup from the right place

Comment: Like I said, use the `--bootstrap-server` option instead of the `--zookeeper` option. The ConsumerGroupCommand.scala supports both clients. Also see `--new-consumer` - but it's not needed, the consumer type is based on which connect option is provided.

Answer (score 0):

When using kafka-consumer-group you should use the bootstrap-server parameter ( instead of zookeeper) if you want to see new implementation consumers ( your spring consumers for instance).

./kafka-consumer-groups.sh --list --bootstrap-server localhost:9092

More information here :
https://riptutorial.com/apache-kafka/example/27968/kafka-consumer-groups

Yannick